# Group together by time difference between records

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My DB is filled with records:

```
{date: ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00Z"), data: 'A'}
{date: ISODate("2018-01-01T02:00Z"), data: 'B'}
{date: ISODate("2018-01-01T10:00Z"), data: 'C'}
{date: ISODate("2018-01-01T16:00Z"), data: 'D'}
{date: ISODate("2018-01-01T18:00Z"), data: 'E'}
{date: ISODate("2018-01-01T20:00Z"), data: 'F'}
{date: ISODate("2018-01-01T22:00Z"), data: 'G'}
```

I would like to group records together when the time difference between them is smaller than N.

So for example, when N = 3 hours, first bin should contain A, B, second bin should contain C and the last bin should contain D, E, F, G.

Is it possible with MongoDB's aggregation or mapReduce?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with mongodb aggregation, because you can't access values of 2 documents currently. The more approaching solution will be to use $bucket framework stage.

Comment: Hmm, that's unfortunate. Can you clarify how to achieve that by using $bucket framework?

Comment: Bucket will allow you to group your data by value range, ie from 00:00 to 02:59, from 03:00 to 05:59, 06:00 to 08:59, etc... But you'll never can refer to previous doc to calculate difference between previous and current doc

Comment: Ok, this is grouping by interval - that's completely not what I want. But thanks anyway.